# buffer and play videos faster in VideoView

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, video, amazon-s3, android-videoview

Using Picasso I was able to download and display my images very quickly in my Android app. Now i want to stream my videos from my S3 server and play them through my app faster than my code here:

```
try {
        MediaController VideoController = new MediaController(VideoPlayerActivity.this);//Creates a media controller to this activity.

        VideoController.setAnchorView(AdVideoView);//Adds the media controller to the video view.
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);//Creates a Uri to hold the URL of the video.
        AdVideoView.setMediaController(VideoController);//Add the media controller to the video view.
        AdVideoView.setVideoURI(video);//Make the video view play from the Uri.
    } catch(Exception e) {

        Log.e("Video Stream Error", e.getMessage());//Sets the message for the log.
        e.printStackTrace();//Displays the error in the stack trace.
        e.notify();
    }
```

> Is there a faster way to display videos through a GitHub or better code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The things that usually slow down streamed video playback are server and network related rather than client side - unless you have a very slow or very busy device it is unlikely it won't be able to play the video back at the rate it is received over the network.

Taking this and assuming you are are seeing delays in your streamed videos, there are a couple of common things to look for.

First, mp4 videos in normal format have the metadata at the end of the video file which is not good for streaming. There is a technique called quickstart, which moves the metadata to the start which you definitely want to use. More info here:

- http://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/

Secondly, network connections can obviously vary and slow networks make streaming high quality video files a problem. A technique called adaptive bit rate streaming (ABR) allows the client request lower quality video 'chunks' if the network quality is bad and then change to higher quality when it improves.

ABR also helps startup time as it allows you quickly start the video stream by using a lower quality level, and hence smaller size chunk, and then increase the quality as the video progresses. You can see this effect when you start up most online video services, such as Netflix, today (July 2016).

One thing to note is that video hosting and streaming is a specialist area so it is generally easier to leverage existing streaming technologies and services rather than to build them your self. Some good places to look to get a feel for open source solutions:

- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org
- http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html